# Moving from DTL processes to DLT processes (using DBT)

Tags: postgresql, airflow, ddl, dbt

I'm trying to move from a DTL script to this a DLT DBT script. The problem is that in one of my tables I also have some other DTL processes that writes in. I read https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/migration/tools/migrating-from-stored-procedures/1-migrating-from-stored-procedures but didn't figure out how should I set my last tables to be able to write inside it. Maybe somebody else got stuck in this.

The flow is like in picture. [image: The flow is like in picture.]
The `int__log_client__deletes` & `int__log_client_do__delete` have to write also in tables `client_dim` & `audit_matching_log`   without deleting the table.

The original `int__log_client__do_delete` script segment looks something like:

```
update data_warehouse.client_dim
       set is_deleted = true,
       deleted_at = current_timestamp
 where client_id in (select client_id from deletes)
   and source_id = 1
   returning 'delete' as type, client_id as key
```

The other original one is something like this but with insert in it.

My current view is something like:

```
{{ config( materialized='????' ) }}
with

do_delete as
(
    select
        some_columns,
        true as to_delete,
        current_timestamp as deleted_at
    from {{  ref('stg__data_warehouse__client_dim') }}
    where client_id in (select client_id from {{ ref('int__log_client__deletes') }})
        and client_dim_source_id = 1
--    returning 'delete' as type, client_id as key
)

select * from do_delete
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trial & error and getting cycle issues I got a working using a post_hook config in

> int__data_warehouse__client_dim_with_deletes.sql

Something like:

```
{{
config(
    post_hook="update {{ source('data_warehouse','client_dim') }}
               set is_deleted = true,
                   deleted_at = {{ dbt_date.now() }}
               where client_id in (select client_id from {{ this }})
                   and source_id = 1"
       )
 }}

with
do_delete as
(
    select
        some_columns
    from {{  ref('stg__data_warehouse__client_dim') }}
    where client_id in (select client_id from {{ ref('int__log_client__deletes') }})
        and client_dim_source_id = 1
--    returning 'delete' as type, client_id as key
)

select * from do_delete
```

That's the working solution for my need!

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-think everything as a `select` statement. In this case, I would just add a field to the `stg__data_warehouse__client_dim` model that sets `is_deleted` appropriately. (Ideally you would have a `created_at` in your `deletes` table that also gives you `deleted_at`):

```sql
-- in stg__data_warehouse__client_dim.sql

with
    existing_logic as (
        -- your existing stg__data_warehouse__client_dim model
    ),
    deletes as (select * from {{ ref('int__log_client__deletes') }}),
select
    existing_logic.*,
    case when deletes.client_id is not null then true else false end as to_delete,
    deletes.created_at as deleted_at
from existing_logic
left join deletes on existing_logic.client_id = deletes.client_id
```

If this is too much logic for a `stg` model, then just create an `int` model downstream. The code is the same!

```sql
-- in int__data_warehouse__client_dim_with_deletes.sql

with
    existing_logic as (select * from {{ ref('stg__data_warehouse__client_dim') }}),
    deletes as (select * from {{ ref('int__log_client__deletes') }}),
select
    existing_logic.*,
    case when deletes.client_id is not null then true else false end as to_delete,
    deletes.created_at as deleted_at
from existing_logic
left join deletes on existing_logic.client_id = deletes.client_id
```

Comment: Thanks for details @tconbeer, I'm just wondering, to be sure... my staging source is from other schema, when I do in "stg_" it will update the original , but when I do the "int_" it will update a local table called <target_dbt>."int.." ?

Comment: Tried a basic insert in the staging table but returned circular error... tried something like `select * from {{ source(...) }} union all select * from {{ ref(...) }}`. Is there anyway to overcome this?